# Bad wrapping of long words in question titles on S.E. landing page

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, title, stackexchange.com

I saw this pop up on the real-time 'recently active questions' list on the [Stack Exchange landing page](https://stackexchange.com/):

[image: Yuck]

I know this is a minor thing, and anyway that question will disappear in a few seconds and be replaced a new one—hopefully one that doesn't have such a long word in it's title.

Adding this CSS fixes it quite nicely in Chrome, though it will probably need to be tweaked to support other browsers:

```
.realtime-title {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[image: Yay]
<sup>Of course, I had to fake that by editing the DOM in the browser; the original had disappeared already.</sup>

Comment: Of course, the real win would be teaching people to avoid nondescript titles like "this boolean API call returns false...". Barring that, your CSS fix should be [compatible  IE8+](http://caniuse.com/#search=overflow-wrap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed and will be deployed in the next build.